# LAST_INSERT_ID() after INSERT INTO error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with LAST_INSERT_ID() (or mysql_insert_id on php) and a table with two parameters (for this example).
ID: autoincremental value
TEXT: varchar unique field.

If I have this:

```
INSERT INTO field (text) VALUES ('a');  -> Insert OK
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); -> ok, returns 1;
INSERT INTO field (text) VALUES ('a');  -> Insert Error (text field is UNIQUE)
INSERT INTO field (text) VALUES ('b');  -> Insert Ok
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); -> ok, but returns 3, not 2
```

The autoincremental field isn't correlative, and jump the 2 value.
I try whith START TRANSACTION and ROLLBACK or COMMIT, but I have the same problem (or maybe, I don't do it correctly).

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, an incremental ID isn't always MAX+1, nor do they reshuffle if you delete an earlier record in sequence. It shouldn't matter if you have gaps in the sequence of your incremental IDs: if you're using incremental IDs correctly as unique identifiers, then this is NOT A PROBLEM. If you're dependent on a consecutive sequence, then you haven't designed your database correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you provide some idea to desing my database correctly? I need an ID with a consecutive sequence. If I do an INSERT INTO but it fails, I need the next INSERT INTO returns the ID+1, not ID + 2,3,4...

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, consecutive ID numbers should not be critical. If your circumstances dictate that you do need ID numbers with a guaranteed consecutive sequence - e.g. for invoice numbers where the taxman might notice gaps when checking the books - then you have to do this manually. Keep the autoincrement column as your primary key, but have an invNo column that you populate through your code (whether a database trigger ON INSERT, or your PHP). You can always INSERT without the invNo, then UPDATE to add the invNo value later.

Comment: You need to watch out for multiple users trying to insert at the same time. Normally I'd have a separate "numbers" table with a single row where I hold the next number to use. When inserting a new invoice, lock that table to prevent multiple concurrent access, read the next number to use, then increment and UPDATE, then use for my invoice record... all within the one transaction. If the insert invoice fails, then rollback to revert the next number table as well. If you find the numbers table locked, then retry a couple of times before failing cleanly.

Comment: Thanks again, I will redesing my data base, and try that.

Comment: Note that you do need to be working with a transactional database for this to work